# Bash - delayed evaluation of wildcard fie execution: how does it work

Tags: bash, shell

I have been trying to understand why Bash parses the following in the way I desire, but not the way I would expect from a reading of the Bash Reference Manual (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). From that manual, I understand that wildcards, such as the first line contains, are processed through filename expansion before the command is executed. However, the second for loop contains another wildcard. If it were evaluated at the time of the command line processing, it would not match the files in the subdirectories. But that is exactly how it behaves. The second wildcard is not evaluated until run-time, after the cd command completes. How does Bash do this? I would imagine it is terribly entangled evaluation of the command line.

```
for d in *;do
  cd "$d"
  for f in *.zip; do
    7z x "$f"
  done
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: Wildcard expansion happens separately for each (sub-)command that bash executes.

Comment: This still isn't clear. The expansion happens during the evaluation of the command prior to execution. So, are you saying a sub-command is everything in the outer for loop? The *.zip expansion would have to be down each iteration of the outer for loop and after the cd command completes. This doesn't seem to be consistent with the manual.

Comment: @KevinBuchs it's true for simple commands not for compound commands see 3.2 Shell Commands, note that this is also the case for other posix shells http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update from comments

Expansions as described in 3.5 are for simple commands, for compound commands the chapter 3.2 Shell Commands, describes how they are turn to simple commands

> 3.2.3
> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Commands separated by a ‘;’ are executed sequentially; the shell waits for each command to terminate in turn.

## Original answer was

from differents parts of bash manual

> for
>
> The syntax of the for command is:
>
> for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done
>
> Expand words, and execute commands once for each member in the resultant list, with name bound to the current member. *[...]*

And about "words" expansion

> 3.5 Shell Expansions
>
> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into tokens. There are seven kinds of expansion performed:
>
> - brace expansion
> - tilde expansion
> - parameter and variable expansion
> - command substitution
> - arithmetic expansion
> - word splitting
> - filename expansion

More particularly `*` goes in filename expansion (the last after word splitting so no risk to split filename containing spaces)

> 3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching
>
> *
>
> Matches any string, including the null string.

About your command note that in first loop if a file is not a directory it will try to `cd` leading to an error and the `cd ..` will be executed as there is no error checking

Could be improved

```
for d in *;do
    [[ -d $d ]] || continue   # to skip files that are not a directory
    cd "$d" || continue       # to skip directory if `cd` fails
    for f in *.zip; do
        7z x "$f"
    done
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: You could avoid the test for directories with `for d in */; do`.

Comment: I knew the requirements for that script and didn't need to test for non-directories.

In the end, however, you have not answered my question. You didn't address the specific issue I raised.

Comment: ok i understood better the question, the second for command is evaluated (words are expanded) for each cycle of first loop, you can also consider `x=hello; echo "$x"`, the variable isn't set at the time the command sequence is parsed, but the expansion happens before echo is called

Comment: Finally the chapter that covers this is the 3.2 and more exactly 3.2.3 and 3.2.4

Comment: I believe the missing information in the manual should be inserted in section 3.1.1, where the steps of processing are listed. Step 3: Parses the tokens into simple and compound commands. Step 4: Performs the various shell expansions. They should not list these as linear steps. Step 3+ should say that for each command (simple or an element of a compound command) the following steps are performed, one at a time. Then steps 4-7 should be nested under step 3+, like 3+a, 3+b, 3+c, 3+d.

Comment: Marking this as an answer, with the caveat that the real answer comes in the comments. It would be good for you to edit your answer, @NahuelFouilleul so the true answer is not just in the comments.